# Understanding the code for a character-counting program

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm struggling to understand how the following code works. I used Python Visualiser but the process doesn't seem to make sense to me. The main source of confusion for me is to do with the `setdefault()` line and the `count[character]` line in the `for` loop.

```
message = 'This is a random sentence that forms a message'
count = {}

for character in message.upper():  
    count.setdefault(character, 0)
    count[character] = count[character] + 1

print(count)
```

Comment: What do you not understand about `setdefault()`, and what do you not understand about `count[character]`?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation of `setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)?

Comment: Keep reminding yourself that count is a dictionary, not some integer counter.

Comment: @mkrieger1 with setdefault() I was confused about how it functions when a repeated character comes up. With count[character] I was incorrectly viewing it as an integer counter as Ronald mentioned.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thank you, I didn't consider reading the documentation. It's cleared up alot of confusion for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with initializing your variables:

```
message = 'This is a random sentence that forms a message'
count = {}
```

The first line is trivial, the second line makes an empty dictionary where you will store the amount of times a certain letter occurs in `message`.

```
for character in message.upper():
```

Here you will start looping over all letters in the message but first all letters are made capitals with `.upper()`.

```
count.setdefault(character, 0)
```

If the key `character` is not yet in the dictionary `count`, it is inserted with default value 0. You can read more about this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

```
count[character] = count[character] + 1
```

This line will increase the value of `character` with 1. This line could be simplified by `count[character] += 1` wich does the exact same.

Comment: Thank you!! This makes alot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

As [mad_'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62331800/3129414) and [debsim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62331852/3129414) of this question already explain the usage of `setdefault`'s behavior, I am not repeating them.

I am showing three different ways(including your's one), to count the occurrences of each character of a string (case insensitive).

```
from collections import Counter


def count_chars_1(message):
    count = {}
    for character in message.upper():  
        count.setdefault(character, 0)
        count[character] = count[character] + 1
    return count

def count_chars_2(message):
    count = {}
    for character in message.upper():  
        count[character] = count.get(character, 0)+1
    return count

def count_chars_3(message):
    return dict(Counter(message.upper()))

message = 'This is a random sentence that forms a message'
print(count_chars_1(message))
print(count_chars_2(message))
print(count_chars_3(message))
```

Output:

```
{'T': 4, 'H': 2, 'I': 2, 'S': 6, ' ': 8, 'A': 5, 'R': 2, 'N': 3, 'D': 1, 'O': 2, 'M': 3, 'E': 5, 'C': 1, 'F': 1, 'G': 1}
{'T': 4, 'H': 2, 'I': 2, 'S': 6, ' ': 8, 'A': 5, 'R': 2, 'N': 3, 'D': 1, 'O': 2, 'M': 3, 'E': 5, 'C': 1, 'F': 1, 'G': 1}
{'T': 4, 'H': 2, 'I': 2, 'S': 6, ' ': 8, 'A': 5, 'R': 2, 'N': 3, 'D': 1, 'O': 2, 'M': 3, 'E': 5, 'C': 1, 'F': 1, 'G': 1}
```

Explanation:

- In `count_chars_2` method, I am searching for the character in `count` dictionary by using `.get` method and if the character is not found then it sets the occurrence of that character to 0. [Documentation on get method can be found here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).
- In `count_chars_3` I am utilizing the `Counter` method of `collections` package to count the occurrences. `count_chars_3` returns a `dict` object to meet your criteria. Details on `Counter` can be read [from the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects).

Comment: Thank you! the count_chars_2 and count_chars_3 method is alot more intuitive than the one I've used. I very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your example [setdefault()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) is simply setting frequency of occurrence of each character to 0 for keys not present in the dict `count`.

`count[character]` is the syntax of accessing the values of key in dict. In this case `character` is the key.

```
message = 'This is a random sentence that forms a message' # text for which we want to find character frequency
count = {} # initiate the dictionary

for character in message.upper(): # Loop over every character in string coverted to upper case 
    count.setdefault(character, 0) # set the count of each character which is not yet present as a key in count dict to 0
    count[character] = count[character] + 1 # initiate the value by 1

print(count)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes alot more sense now.